# Show that the limit of distributions is Dirac delta

Tags: limits, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I would like to show that the following statement is true

$
\lim_{a\searrow 0} \theta(x)\frac{x^{1-a}}{\Gamma(a)} = \delta(x). 
$

$\Gamma$ is the gamma function. The above limit is in the sense of distribution, i.e.

$
 \lim_{a\searrow 0} \int d x\, f(x) \theta(x)\frac{x^{1-a}}{\Gamma(a)} = f(0)
$

for any test function $f$.

Comment: Did you try anything? Did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a test function $\phi$ with support in $[-1,1]$. Then the integral writes
$$\int_{0}^1\frac{x^{1-a}}{\Gamma(a)}\phi(x)dx $$

Obviously, for $a \le 1 $
$$0\le \int_{0}^1\frac{x^{1-a}}{\Gamma(a)}\phi(x)dx \le\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)} \int_{0}^1 \phi(x)dx\to 0\text{ as }a\to 0^+,$$

hence your hypothesis is false.

Comment: The downvoters, care to explain why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

As it was already explained above, the sequence of function-type distributions, *i.e.* distributions in $\mathscr D'(\mathbb R)$ which are in fact functions in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R)$,
$$
\tau_a=\theta(x)\frac{x^{1-a}}{\Gamma(a)}, \text{ for }a>0,
$$
does not converge to $\delta(x)$ as $a\to 0.$ A very quick, informal way to see this is to note that, letting
$$
\theta(x)=
\begin{cases}
1\text{ if }x\ge0\\
0\text{ if }x<0,
\end{cases}
$$ 
then, for an arbitrary but fixed $x\in\mathbb R$,
$$ 
\lim_{a\to0 }\theta(x)\frac{x^{1-a}}{\Gamma(a)}=0,
$$
from here we see that the sequence has no hope of converging to $\delta$.

This argument is made rigorous as follows: notice that the definition of $\theta$ function is not restrictive, since altering is value only at the origin cannot affect the value of any integral it appears in.
Then, letting $\varphi\in\mathscr D(\mathbb R)$, with support enclosed in the ball $B_R$ of radius $R$ centred at the origin,
$$
\langle \tau_a,\varphi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\tau_a(x)\varphi(x)dx
$$
and we can pull the limit $a\to0$ under the integral sign thanks to Lebesgue's theorem, getting $0$, since the integrand is dominated for small $a$ by
$$
R\chi_{B_R}(x)
$$
which is summable ($\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$).

As an exercise, one can follow your example and look for a sequence of distributions involving the $\Gamma$ function and which do converge to $\delta$. Consider the functions
$$
\rho_\varepsilon(t,x) \equiv \frac{e^{-|t|/\varepsilon}|t|^{x-1}}{2\Gamma(x)}\varepsilon^{-x},\text{ for }x>0.
$$
Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{-|t|/\varepsilon}|t|^{x-1}}{2\Gamma(x)}\varepsilon^{-x}\varphi(t) dt= \int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{-|s|}|s|^{x-1}}{2\Gamma(x)}\varphi(\varepsilon s)ds;
$$
by Lebesgue's theorem, since the integrand is dominated by 
$$
\sup_{\text{supp}\varphi}|\varphi|\frac{e^{-|s|}|s|^{x-1}}{2\Gamma(x)}
$$
and
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{-|s|}|s|^{x-1}}{2\Gamma(x)} ds = \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\rho}\rho^{x-1}d\rho=1,
$$
finally
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\rho_\varepsilon(t,x)=\delta(t)\text{ for }x>0.
$$